# Merging fgetc and putchar in while loop

Tags: c, fgetc, putchar

I am writing a simple code to print the content of the file to stdout.

When i use this :

```
while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)putchar(c);
```

It works like it should but i wanna to merge `putchar` and `fgetc`. So i wrote

```
while(putchar(fgetc(fp))!=EOF);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. So i check the return value of `putchar`

```
RETURN VALUE
       fputc(),  putc()  and  putchar()  return  the  character  written as an
       unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on error.
```

So why it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you think `putchar(EOF)` does?

Comment: I think it maybe should evaluate to `EOF`

Comment: But *why* do you want to write `EOF` to the output? Anyway, `EOF` is not `unsigned char` so it won't work.

Comment: @Chaker.benhamed Where does it say that `putchar` won't write anything if the argument is `EOF`? And why do you think that `putchar` will return `EOF` if there *wasn't* an error, when the documentation says it returns `EOF` on error?

Comment: No i don't want to write `EOF` to the output but what i understand from `Linux Programmer's Manual` that `putchar` return `EOF` int the case of error.

Comment: Yes but that is if `putchar()` fails, not the echo of what you write. Please just stick to your first method, which worked.

Comment: But shouldn't `putchar` fails since `EOF` is not an ASCII value?

Comment: Its failure is a property of the output stream, not what you send it. Sending `EOF` does *not* tell it to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` returns one of the following:

- A character, represented as an `unsigned char` value (e.g. typically between 0 and 255, inclusive of those values), converted to an `int`. Thus, there are typically one of 256 (`UCHAR_MAX+1`, technically) values that fall into this category.
- A non-character, `EOF`, which has a negative value, typically -1.

Thus, `getchar` may typically return one of **257** (not 256) values. If you attempt to convert that value straight to `char` or `unsigned char` (e.g. by calling `putchar`), you'll be losing the `EOF` information.

For this reason you need to store the return value of `getchar` into an `int` **before** you convert it to an `unsigned char` or `char`.